# What are the differences between to.equal(true) and to.be.true?

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm learning Mocha and Chai.

I try understand when I have to use `to.equal(true)` or `to.be.true` to know which is better in different kind of situations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My understanding from the [docs](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_language-chains) is that `.to` and `.be` and various other pieces of the Expect/Should syntax are just syntactical sugar, with no real functionality.

So `.to.be.true` === `.true` and `.to.equal(true)` === `.equal(true)`. So the difference, if any, is between `.true` and `.equal(true)` -- and there isn't any difference; `.true` is just a syntactical shorthand for `.equal(true)`.

Answer (score 4):

**They test the same thing.** In other words, wherever `.to.equal(true)` fails, `.to.be.true` will also fail, and where `.to.equal(true)` succeeds, so does `.to.be.true`.

However, **they do differ** in that `.to.equal` takes an optional custom error message whereas `.to.be.true` does not take a custom error message.

```
var settings = {
    verbose: "foo"
};
settings.verbose.should.equal(true, "verbose setting");
```

will show an error message like:

```
AssertionError: verbose setting: expected 'foo' to equal true
```

Same thing with `expect(settings.verbose).to.equal(true, "verbose setting")`. Without the custom error message, the error will be:

```
AssertionError: expected 'foo' to equal true
```

If you use `expect(settings.verbose).to.be.true("verbose setting")` the test will fail but the custom error message will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

it doens't look there are any differences

https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L298

https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L502